# how to calculate percentile of each 15 rows in python

Tags: python, pandas, function, loops, for-loop

I have 810 rows in my data frame about vehicle speed and I was trying to calculate the 85th percentile speed for each 15 rows. Here what I did so far:

```
count = 0
stat1 = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if count == 10:
        stat1 = df.dbl_v.quantile(0.85)
        count = 0
    else:
        count += 1
```

how can I store and see the 85th percentile speed? It's supposed to be there are 54 of 85th percentile speed.

Thankyou

Comment: try `df.groupby(df.index // 15)['dbl_v'].quantile(0.85)`

Comment: thankyou for your help!

Comment: It worked? if yes i make an appropriate answer

Comment: what if I add more percentile to calculate, is it possible to save it into new data frame?

Comment: yes it works, I can clearly see all the desired 85th percentile speed

Comment: Yes, it's possible. For that I will need you to share a sample of your data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create groups every 15 lines using the remainder of the division by 15

```
grouper = df.groupby(df.index // 15)
```

To create a new DF by applying `.quantile` to multiple columns, we can do this:

```
df_new = grouper.agg(
               quantile85 = ('dbl_v', lambda x: x.quantile(0.85))
              ,quantile20 = ('other_column', lambda x: x.quantile(0.20))
              ,mean_dbl_v = ('dbl_v', 'mean')
              ,sum_col3 = ('name_column3', 'sum')
               #and so on...
           )
```

Comment: thankyou! Beside percentile, I also want to calculate the mean, median and also other percentile of every 15 rows. How will the for loop function turns to?

Comment: i add more examples of aggregations, please see update :-)

Comment: thankyou, you help me a lot! Basically, I dont need for loop function to iterate them. All I need is groupby and also aggregate function. Thankyou!

Comment: @urtaeyang if my answer helped you, please [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) :-)